# How do I set up a deep relation in Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, has-many-through

Consider the following world model:

- A User can be member of zero or more UserGroups
- A UserGroup can have zero or more User members
- A Repo can reside in zero or more RepoGroups
- A RepoGroup can contain zero or more Repos
- A UserGroup can be granted 'read' or 'write' access to a RepoGroup

The (simplified) database schema implementing this model looks like this:

[image: Database schema]

Setting up the Eloquent many-to-many relationship between User and UserGroup via the user_group_pivot table is straight forward, as is the equivalent relationship between Repo and RepoGroup. The access_rights table is a pivot table with additional access information, but the relationship between ClientGroup and RepoGroup is also many-to-many, and equally straight forward. Now the following challenges remain:

1. The relationship between UserGroup and Repo
2. The relationship between RepoGroup and User
3. The relationship between User and Repo

This is the code I've got so far:

```
class User extends Model {
    public function userGroups() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(UserGroup::class, 'user_group_pivot');
    }

    public function repos() {
        # Eloquent wizard can makez magic here?
    }

    public function repoGroups() {
        # Eloquent wizard can makez magic here?
    }
}

class UserGroup extends Model {
    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_group_pivot');
    }

    public function repos() {
        # Eloquent wizard can makez magic here?
    }

    public function repoGroups() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(RepoGroup::class, 'access_rights')
            ->withPivot(['access']);
    }

}

class RepoGroup extends Model {
    public function repos() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Repo::class, 'repo_group_pivot');
    }

    public function users() {
        # Eloquent wizard can makez magic here?
    }

    public function userGroups() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(UserGroup::class, 'access_rights')
            ->withPivot(['access']);
    }
}

class Repo extends Model {
    public function repoGroups() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(RepoGroup::class, 'repo_group_pivot');
    }

    public function repos() {
        # Eloquent wizard can makez magic here?
    }

    public function repoGroups() {
        # Eloquent wizard can makez magic here?
    }
}
```

I've scoured the web looking for examples similar to this, but they either blatantly plagiarize the Laravel docs or are equally trivial. I've been playing around with the Model::hasManyThrough() relationship, but to no avail. Hence I put my hopes in the Eloquent wizards of the world. I can haz helps, pliis?

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility to go to repos without touching other relations.

You can add code like this below to `User::repos`

```
$repos = [];
foreach($user->userGroups() as $userGroup){
   foreach($userGroup->repoGroups() as $repoGroup){
       foreach($repoGroup->repos() as $repo){
          $repos[] = $repo;
   }
}
```

If you are worried about performence (example during processing a lot of users) you can use eager loading during fetch users with repos from DB

```
$users = App\User::with(['userGroups.repoGroups.repos'])->get();
```